# Why is my cilantro seedlings stem so long and barely any leaves? And How can i make it grow nicely?

Tags: planting, seedlings, herbs, cilantro

I have included a picture of different pots i used to plant my cilantro/ coriander. It has been 3 weeks since germination and planting. I added some dried grass mulch so that it doesn't grow too long with mostly stems. Is what I am doing ok?[image]

Some looks great and some looks like its growing too long without leaves.

I am in zone 5 in Seattle Wa today is OCT 4,2021

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I’m afraid you set up your seedlings for a lethal race: There are so many seedlings per area, that they are trying to outcompete their neighbors in search of space, light and nutrition by stretching as long as they can. Looking at the window box, that’s even worse - for them, the high sides is like being at the bottom of a deep valley.

Next time, be a bit more light-handed and use a lot less seed, off the cuff, I’d say a fifth should be plenty.

For the existing batch, you can either wait and see how many will succeed and watch them self-regulate, but they will get even lankier and them being so crowded increases the risk of e.g. fungal infections, which can at worst cost you the whole lot. Instead, gently pull out the majority of the seedlings, disturbing the remaining ones as little as possible. If necessary, cut or pinch them off right at the soil surface. If you can manage to raise the ones in the window box, that would also be good, but it’s probably not feasible - and at the current state with just the cotyledons they are too young to be transplanted.

The grass clippings don’t help at all, at worst they can harbor disease or feed fungi, that could move on to the seedlings.

Answer (score -1):

Not too much water and cilantro is one you want to reim  often it will flourish. I usually can keep mine going most of the summer thy usually make it most of the summer in my region the hot August sun will get them I van get a few more weeks in pots inside

Comment: Can you edit your answer to make it clearer?